# Exporting BIRT report into CSV

Tags: csv, export, birt

I am Using BIRT for reporting in my project.
The report shows correct value for amount(String) as 123456789123, but when i try to export the same report into csv, the csv file shows same amount as 1.234E11.
I want to value as 123456789123 in csv too.
Please help
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I imagine this is probably an issue with viewing it in Excel.  Exporting data does not export format codes.  Open the csv in notepad and you will see the correct data.  If you export the report to excel you can set a custom format code like #####0 in the Format Number property in the properties editor for the data item.

Comment: Exactly, this is not a BIRT problem, the problem is the way Excel is opening the CSV file.

Answer (score 0):

If the number is too large excel will display the value like that. If you expand the column and set the column to number under format cells it will display correctly. You will need to save it as an excel workbook.

Answer (score 0):

We just had this problem with the our BiRT reporting tool.  When we opened the exported file in a text editor the number was formatted in scientific notation.  This was a bug with one of Birt's custom formatters.

We had to look at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.dataextraction.impl.CommonDataExtractionImpl and change the line

```
valueFormatters[i] = new NumberFormatter( patterns[i], this.locale );
```

to

```
String pattern = patterns[i] == null ? "Unformatted" : patterns[i];
valueFormatters[i] = new NumberFormatter( pattern, this.locale );
```

Setting the pattern to "Unformatted" made default format stay as a normal integer rather than scientific notation (via a decimal formatter).